# Выравнивание объектов от края страницы

Tags: html, css

Вывожу на страницу элементы списка под соответствующими заголовками, но столкнулся с тем, что при команде margin отступ идет не от края страницы браузера, а от предыдущего блока. Поэтому столбцы съезжают, если использовать объекты разной длины.

Как выровнять столбцы от края страницы, не используя форматирование таблицей?

```
        <span style = "margin-left: 75px">
    <%
        out.print(gm.getGenre() + ";");
    %>
    </span>
    <span style = "margin-left: 75px">
    <%
        out.print(gm.getName() + ";");
    %>
    </span>
    <span style = "margin-left: 90px">
    <%
        out.print(gm.getPrice());
    %>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Margin и должен быть от края предидушего блока.  Стесняюсь спросит шо это за формат... `HTML` странный

Comment: Это код JSP-файла, который отображет одну из страниц web-приложения на java. Но вопрос остается - можно ли как-то зафиксировать объекты по отношению в полям страницы, а не друг к другу?

Comment: я так понимаю что надо к правому краю прижать кнопку `удалить` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть таблицы устарели но на мой взгляд это делать лучше таблицами

```html
<table align="center" cellpadding="10px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Жанр</td>
      <td>Название</td>
      <td>Цена</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>$5</td>
    <td><button>кнопка</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>$12</td>
    <td><button>кнопка</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>$71</td>
    <td><button>кнопка</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Таблицы не устарели и никогда не устареют. Просто их нужно использовать там, где это уместно. Если данные требуют вывода в табличном виде, то именно таблица и подходит для таких целей. ;)

Comment: P.S. Только атрибуты `cellpadding`, `align` и т.д., которые точно устарели, нужно убрать и установить стили в CSS

Comment: @Deonis кто сказал убрать cellpadding и align ? если к примеру сменить doctype то совсем ни чего  устаревшего нету

Answer (score 1):

Может быть подойдёт flexbox

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.flex span {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span>жанр</span>
  <span>название</span>
  <span>цена($)</span>
  <span><button style="opacity:0;pointer-events:none;">удалить</button></span>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <span>рок</span>
  <span>кино</span>
  <span>12($)</span>
  <span><button>удалить</button></span>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <span>классика</span>
  <span>шуберт</span>
  <span>21($)</span>
  <span><button>удалить</button></span>
</div>
```